# Как создать скрипт комментариев на php?

Tags: php

Нужен скрипт комментариев, который будет вписывать комменты в текстовый файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уважаемый,тут вам не фрилансеры сидят, за вас писть тут никто не чего не будет, а вот идеи подкинуть мы можем спрашивайте что конкретно непонятно?

**UPD:** Работа с файлами разделяется на 3 этапа:

- Открытие файла.
- Манипуляции с данными.
- Закрытие файла.

**Открытие файла:**

Для того чтобы открыть файл в среде PHP используется функция fopen(). Обязательными параметрами этой функции является имя файла и режим файла.

Согласно документации PHP выделяют следующие виды режимов файлов:

- r – открытие файла только для чтения.
- r+ - открытие файла одновременно на чтение и запись.
- w – создание нового пустого файла. Если на момент вызова уже существует такой файл, то он уничтожается.
- w+ - аналогичен r+, только если на момент вызова фай такой существует, его содержимое удаляется.
- a – открывает существующий файл в  режиме записи, при этом указатель сдвигается на  последний байт файла (на конец файла).
- a+ - открывает файл в режиме чтения и записи при этом указатель сдвигается на последний байт файла (на конец файла). Содержимое файла не удаляется.

Пример:

```
<?php
//Открывает файл в разных режимах
$fp = fopen('counter.txt', 'r'); // Бинарный режим
$fp = fopen('counter.txt', 'rt'); // Текстовый режим
$fp = fopen("http://www.yandex.ru", "r");// Открывает HTTP соединение на чтение
$fp = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.ru", 'w'); //Открываем FTP соединение с указанием логина и пароля
?>
```

**Манипуляции с данными файла**

Записывать данные в файл при помощи PHP можно при помощи функции fwrite().  Это функция принимает 2 обязательных параметра и 1 необязательный. В качестве обязательных параметров выступает дескриптор файла и режим файла:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "a"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи 
$mytext = "Это строку необходимо нам записать\r\n"; // Исходная строка
$test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); // Запись в файл
if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
?>
```

Для построчного считывания файла используют функцию fgets().  Функция принимает 2 обязательных параметра:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); // Открываем файл в режиме чтения
if ($fp) 
{
while (!feof($fp))
{
$mytext = fgets($fp, 999);
echo $mytext."<br />";
}
}
else echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Закрытие файла**

Закрытие файла происходить с помощью функции fclose(), которая принимает 1 обязательный параметр.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
if ($fp)
{
echo 'Файл открыт';
fclose($fp); // Закрытие файла
}
?>
```

**Готовое решение:**

А если вам нужен говтовый скрипт тогда вам [сюда](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+php+script+comments)

**UPD2:** Ответ для furian:

Может вы имеете ввиду htmlspecialchars под specialchars?

Производятся следующие преобразования:

- '&' (амперсанд) преобразуется в '&amp;'
- '"' (двойная кавычка) преобразуется в '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- ''' (одиночная кавычка) преобразуется в '&#039;' только в режиме ENT_QUOTES.
- '<' (знак "меньше чем") преобразуется в '&lt;'
- '>' (знак "больше чем") преобразуется в '&gt;'

Пример использования htmlspecialchars:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

Comment: а возможно ли в этом скрипте всавка защитного specialchars? я просто не могу понять куда именно можно его вставить....

Comment: furian ответ для вас выше

Answer (score 0):

а я бы их ни в текстовый файл вписывал, а в БД, ассоциируя со статьей к которой был сделан комментарий, php вам в руки.

Comment: я просто с бд не очень дружу..(((

Comment: так подружитесь.